# how to compare ipv6 address in c without using memcmp

Tags: c, ipv6

I have two ipv6 address stored in structure  `struct in6_addr`. I would like to find which one is smaller without using `memcmp`. Is there a better way to compare ipv6 addresses?

```
struct in6_addr {
       unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   /* IPv6 address */
};
```

Comment: What is the type definition of `struct in6_addr`?

Comment: Why not iterate over `s6_addr` field to compare it one by one with less than operator ?

Comment: And why you cannot use `memcmp` on 2 `s6_addr` members? Seems like the most simple way to do the compare.

Comment: i can use memcmp. But what if compiler adds alignment buffer space which might be different in two structures. ?

Comment: If you take the address of `s6_addr` member directly `memcmp(&a.s6_addr, &b.s6_addr, 16)`, you don't need to worry about struct padding.

Comment: Also, there is never padding before the first member of the struct, and 2 structures of the same type will always have the same layout. So, for this specific case you *could* do `memcmp(&a, &b, 16)`, but I don't recommend that at all.

Comment: Why don't you simply do == ?

Comment: @V.Kravchenko, in C the `==` operator is neither defined for `struct` nor array types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a general point of view: *write what you want to do*, don't use features or tricks to achieve what you want! Here, if you want compare ip v6, first, define how to compare it, and implement as you have defined.

So don't use `memcmp` when you want to compare logical data. Use it only when you want to compare directly raw memory.

For example, if you decide that you have to compare each element of ipv6 and first different elements says relation between two ipv6, write it:

```
// Not checked code, just an example
// Return 0 if ipA == ipB, -1 if ipA < ipB and 1 if ipA > ipB
int compare_ipv6(struct in6_addr *ipA, struct in6_addr *ipB)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i) // Don't use magic number, here just for example
    {
        if (ipA->s6_addr[i] < ipB->s6_addr[i])
            return -1;
        else if (ipA->s6_addr[i] > ipB->s6_addr[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Concise 2) -> for pointers. 3) if true or false is a result, return not `int` but `bool`. `bool compare_ipv6(struct in6_addr *ipA, struct in6_addr *ipB, int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
        if (ipA->s6_addr[i] != ipB->s6_addr[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}`

Comment: About the third point: Sorry, agree with you! And about the first point: you could get rid of `result` variable and `(result==0)` condition, using `return`. Moreover, you code is not doing a right comparison now: you should immediately `return` on `<` or `>`

Comment: Yes, now it compares properly!